# deployment of a site asp.net and iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I know this is for some of you a stupid question but for me is a real problem. I have never deployed a site before 
What i have done so far:

1) publish the site from visual studio to a folder.

2) added to iis for testing everything works great on the local machine

3) got a static ip for the server

but now i want to make the site public so everyone can access it.
what steps should i take next ? when i type the host name of the site in iis example: `www.mySitesNameHere.com` 
Do i have to by a name on a domain like `.com`

If i buy a name how do i link it to my site?

Thank you very much.

Comment: First of all you need to buy a domain. Second you need to map this domain name to your public folder in IIS. Refer this http://serverfault.com/a/97165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several domain providers like:
[godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/?countryview=1), [name](https://www.name.com/) etc you can use to buy a domain name. These providers also provide you steps to map the domain name to your website. Check out [this](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7620/adding-a-domain-name-in-microsoft-iis-7) link for example. This [link](http://content.websitegear.com/article/domain_setup.htm) explains domain name configuration in details.

Comment: thank you. i will take a quick search for a domain provider and get in touch with the to see if they provide help. I have done the steps as in the link you provided. My only problem is not knowing what step should i do next.